# How to make Logitech MX Master 2S switch bluetooth channels by hidapitester?

Tags: hid, logitech, hidapi

I'm having trouble finding the correct hex to do the trick.

tried something like this, but no result

```bash
for i in {0..5}; do
  for j in {0..15}; do
    for m in {0..15}; do
      t=$(printf "%x%x\n" $j $m);
      sudo ./hidapitester --vidpid 046D:B019 --usage 0x0202 --usagePage 0xFF43 --open --length 7 --send-output 0x10,0x0$i,0x11,0x$t,0x02,0x00,0x00
    done
  done
done
```